# SageMaker gives CannotStartContainerError although I specified an entrypoint

Tags: python, image, docker, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-linux-2

I want to train a custom ML model with SageMaker. The model is written in Python and should be shipped to SageMaker in a Docker image. Here is a simplified version of my Dockerfile (the model sits in the train.py file):

```
FROM amazonlinux:latest

# Install Python 3
RUN yum -y update && yum install -y python3-pip python3-devel gcc && yum clean all

# Install sagemaker-containers (the official SageMaker utils package)
RUN pip3 install --target=/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages sagemaker-containers && rm -rf /root/.cache

# Bring the script with the model to the image 
COPY train.py /opt/ml/code/train.py

ENV SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM train.py
```

Now, if I initialize this image as a SageMaker estimator and then run the `fit` method on this estimator I get the following error:

"AlgorithmError: CannotStartContainerError. Please make sure the container can be run with 'docker run  train'."

In other words: SageMaker is not able to get into the container and run the train.py file. But why? The way I am specifying the entrypoint with `ENV SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM train.py` is recommended in the [docs of the sagemaker-containers package](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-containers/blob/master/README.rst) (see 'How a script is executed inside the container').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a hint in [the AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-training-algo-dockerfile.html) and came up with this solution:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python3.7", "/opt/ml/code/train.py"]
```

With this the container [will run as an executable](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint).

Answer (score 0):

i had this same error while using the ´sagemaker-training’ toolkit.
Try to specify the package version in the ‘pip install’ command. It solved my issue. Not wonder why...